# Return value in a recursive function JAVA

Tags: java, search, return

I have designed a function that recursively calls itself. But the return statement does not do what I want it to do. We have checked with a print that the return is reached, but it doesn't go back to the initial function.
The statement it enters:

```
if(depth==0 && pb.isGoalState()){
            System.out.println("!!!!!WOOOOOW!!!!!");
            return pb;
}
```

The println shows up fine, but when pb is returned things get weird.

When it comes back to the function:

```
result = DLS(pb,depth); //never returns here!!!
System.out.println("Here: "+result.toString());
```

it never prints out the print just above. I don't see what's wrong! I have checked the other methods I designed myself.

```
private puzzleBoard IDS(String initial){
        puzzleBoard pb = new puzzleBoard(initial,0,new Vector<Integer>(),new Vector<puzzleBoard>(),new Vector<puzzleBoard>());
        int depth=0;
        puzzleBoard result=new puzzleBoard("999999999",0,new Vector<Integer>(),new Vector<puzzleBoard>(),new Vector<puzzleBoard>());
        while(true){//Repeat
            System.out.println("DP "+depth);
            result = DLS(pb,depth);
            System.out.println("Here: "+result.toString());
            if(result.isGoalState())
                return result;
            depth++;
        }

        }

    private puzzleBoard DLS(puzzleBoard pb, int depth){
        System.out.println("AVskilj depth "+depth+" "+(depth==0 && pb.isGoalState()));
        pb.printPuzzle();
        if(depth==0 && pb.isGoalState()){
            System.out.println("!!!!!WOOOOOW!!!!!");
            return pb;
        }
        else if(depth>0){
            for(Iterator<puzzleBoard> child = generateSuccessorsIDS(pb).iterator(); child.hasNext();){
                puzzleBoard tmp;
                tmp=child.next();
                tmp.printPuzzle();
                DLS(tmp,(depth-1));
            }

        }
        else
            return new puzzleBoard("999999999",0,new Vector<Integer>(),new Vector<puzzleBoard>(),new Vector<puzzleBoard>());
        return pb;
        }
```

---

So my problem is now still in this part of the code

```
for(Iterator<puzzleBoard> child = generateSuccessorsIDS(pb).iterator(); child.hasNext();){
                DLS(child.next(),(depth-1));
            }
```

When I don't use the return before DLS(child.next(),(depth-1)); it goes through every child as intended, but doesn't store the value because of the missing return. When I use return before it it just goes through the first child in the iterator and ignores the rest, because return statements terminates for loops.

How to solve this? I can't think of another way either.

Comment: You should also google for java coding conventions.

Answer (score 3):

At this iteration :

```
   for(Iterator<puzzleBoard> child = generateSuccessorsIDS(pb).iterator(); child.hasNext();){
                puzzleBoard tmp;
                tmp=child.next();
                tmp.printPuzzle();
                DLS(tmp,(depth-1));
            }
```

Look at line :

```
DLS(tmp,(depth-1));
```

DLS returns a `puzzleBoard` object but you do not use the object returned from this line so the recursive object returned will be ignored. I did not validate the correction of your method but you should start here. and BTW if the number of children boards is big this function can take a long time as you call it on each child.

**EDIT :** This is an exmaple of how you can handle the returned boards from your DLS:

```
 else if(depth>0){
       for(Iterator<puzzleBoard> child = generateSuccessorsIDS(pb).iterator(); child.hasNext();){
                    puzzleBoard tmp;
                    tmp=child.next();
                    tmp.printPuzzle();
                    puzzleBoard resultPB = DLS(tmp,(depth-1));

                    // mergre resultPB with current puzzle board (e.g. pb.addChild(resultPB));
                }

       return pb;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your views. The problem is that when I use return infront of DLS(tmp,(depth-1)), it just seems to evaluate the first of the childrends in the vector. How to solve this? I have no clue. Maybe I'm just a bit confused...

Comment: I do not know the structure of puzzleBoard but I guess the boards returned from DLS at this point should be inserted as childs to the current puzzleBoard object.

Comment: Ok, so for experimental purposes I have created a global variable (!) but things still don't work as expected. I'm printing out to check that this variable, result, has the correct value. Right after that DLS() should end (and not return anything), and result should keep it's value. Apparently it doesn't, any ideas as to why?

Comment: Another question I have is that when I try to return DLS, it just evaluates the first element in the iterator. How to return all? With out return I can't save the value, so it seems.

Comment: Again you need to manage all results returned from DLS (in the iteration loop) and them merge them together (depends on you board implementation) and then return the results merged board. (Look at my edited answed)